# Field generated by a $\pi$-system is contained in $\lambda$-system

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory

$\mathcal{P}$ is a $\pi$-system if it is closed under finite intersections. $\mathcal{L}$ is a $\lambda$-system if it contains $\Omega$, is closed under complements, and is closed under countable disjoint unions. $f(\mathcal{A})$ is the field generated by a class $\mathcal{A}$.

Let $\mathcal{P}$ be a $\pi$-system and $\mathcal{L}$ be a $\lambda$-system. I am trying to show directly (without appealing to Dynkin's $\pi-\lambda$ theorem) that if $\mathcal{P}\subseteq\mathcal{L}$, then $f(\mathcal{P})\subseteq\mathcal{L}$.

I have showed that for a class $\mathcal{A}$, the elements of $f(\mathcal{A})$ can be represented as $\bigcup_{i=1}^{m}\bigcap_{j=1}^{n_{i}}A_{ij}$ where the $m$ sets $\bigcap_{j=1}^{n_{i}}A_{ij}$ are disjoint and either $A_{ij}$ or $A_{ij}^{c}$ is in $\mathcal{A}$. So it suffices to show that if $A_{1}\in\mathcal{P}$ and $A_{2}^{c},\dots,A_{n}^{c}\in\mathcal{P}$, then $\bigcap_{i=1}^{n}A_{i}\in\mathcal{L}$. I have tried using the fact that $\mathcal{L}$ is closed under proper differences but I am not able to make any progress.